# Website will not scroll on mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, scroll, skrollr

[This site](http://www.skeletoncru.com/) will not scroll on mobile. I've seen this issue before but this doesn't appear to be the usual suspect(s). I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `overflow:scroll` should be removed from the `html, body` CSS rule. The body scrolls itself if the content is too long, no need for that particular rule - it will only leads to strange behavior (e.g. in Firefox two scrollbars are displayed to me)

Comment: Sorry, I left that in while I was trying to fix it. Removing that didn't fix it.

Comment: You should delete it anyway. It's hard to test it with having it inside. Which mobile device you use?

Comment: *It's deleted now. I am using an iPhone 4s. I've gotten confirmation that on "Droid" it doesn't work. Didn't ask what device though.

Comment: does not work on chrome on android either. Check if you have a css with a `position:fixed` - i had a similar problem in the past

Comment: *I just got a tip from a buddy. It is the Skrollr library causing it. Just don't know why yet. (I killed the initialization of it in a cloned copy of the index.html file) and that resolved the issue.

Comment: Fine to hear you solve it. Was just typing a comment that says you should disable the "Smooth scrolling", "Skrollr" library and whatever script that gives the body the fixed height and try it again

Comment: I got it sorted. I needed to add an id to the html tag to make this work. It's actually something I missed in the Skrollr documentation. 

https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#what-you-need-in-order-to-support-mobile-browsers