# Highcharts 4.0 iPhone/Touchscreen Scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, highcharts

I recently launched my personal website, grantmcgovern.com

It looks good in a browser and was built to be responsive for mobile displays, however, Highcharts is turning out to be a problem for mobile viewers.

I've read about this happening in the past, and the solution was to include [this script](https://gist.github.com/slawekkolodziej/2983403)

I tried that, but to no avail. I also tried disabling mousetracking, etc, but still no cigar.

Here is how I constructing the chart with jQuery:

```
$('#log').highcharts({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
    },
    title: {
        text: "" // Imported from config.js
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.2f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'white'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Code Construct',
        data: dataArrayFinal
    }]
});
```

And here is my HTML block to which it is constructing the pie chart:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="mainContainer">
    <div class="aboutMe">
        <div id="nameTitle" class="animated tada" id="name">
            <h1 id="titleName">Grant McGovern.</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="subTitle">
            <p>Coder.&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Builder.&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Learner.</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div id="log" style="height:100%"></div>
        <div class="graphSubText">
            <a id="graphSubtext" href="https://github.com/g12mcgov/DevCharts">What is this? Checkout my project, DevCharts!</a>
        </div>s
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS to establish touch-screen scrolling (which works when the Highchart is not present):

```
html, body {
width: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

I'm puzzled as to why my site still refuses to scroll with the Highcharts. You can check it out yourself by visting grantmcgovern.com on your iPhone/Mobile device. I recognize the highchart is not scaled correctly... That's the next fix after this.

Comment: Have you tried removing chart form your page?

In Chrome Device Mode & Mobile Emulation I tried to remove div containing chart from console and I still could not scroll your website.
In android device just before page was fully loaded I am able to scroll but later it is impossible.

Comment: @KacperMadej I found the bug. I'm using the Skrollr library, and it turns out you need to add a tag to the html element called "skrollr-body" to allow mobile support.

Answer (score 2):

I found the bug. I'm using the Skrollr library, and it turns out you need to add a tag to the html element called "skrollr-body" to allow mobile support.

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715187/website-will-not-scroll-on-mobile-devices)